# R: how to initialize list within a list

Tags: r, list

```
list1 <- list()
list1[1] = 1
list1[2] = 2
list2 <- list()
list2[1] = 'a'
list2[2] = 'b'
myList <- list(list1, list2)

> myList
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 2


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] "b"
```

Here, `mylist` is a list within a list and can be indexed by `mylist[[i]][[j]]` where i = 1, 2 and j = 1, 2. How can I initialize a list (can be empty) that can be indexed by i = 1,..., 10 and j = 1,..., 10? That is, I want a sublist of length 10 within a larger list of length 10.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
myList <- replicate(10, vector("list", 10), simplify = FALSE)
```

The `vector()` is used to initialize a list of a certain length. All values will be set to NULL in this case. Then `replicate()` will repeat that list inside a list a certain number of times.